# Pops don't show in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popover

I have this code in my html file:

```
<a href="#" class='nav-link m-2 menu-item' style="color:#ceaa63" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Title" data-content="Some content">
             <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart pr-1"></i>Cart
</a>


<script>
        $(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And after click on Cart pop doesn't show. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the `popover` and `jquery` dependent functions before the script files are loaded.

Place your script file at the end, after the `jquery, popover and bootstrap.min.js` files are loaded.

```js
(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='nav-link m-2 menu-item' style="color:#ceaa63" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Title" data-content="Some content">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart pr-1"></i>Cart
</a>
```

Comment: I replaced my script to yours and it still doesn't work

Comment: It seems like, you are loading script before your `html` code is loaded.

Comment: script is before </body> tag

Comment: @LeTeeL - Load your script file after all the other script files are loaded i:e bootstrap, popover and jquery. Or place your code inside  `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at line `$('[data-toggle="popover"]'.popover()`

Comment: @LeTeeL - The code posted in your question has incorrect `script` sequence. Place the `script` with your `popover` code at the end. i:e `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script> $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); </script>
`

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks a lot, sequence was wrong and now work even my first version of script, thank you very much! :)